# Redirect from server root directory to apache root directory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, directory, root

I have made simple http server on Ubuntu 14.04 with LAMP and put my html, php and js files to apache root directory **/var/www/**. All paths within these files are absolute and looks like **/script1.php** or **/subdir/script.php**. Directory tree of web server looks like:

```
/
|---var
    |---www
        |---script1.php
        |---subdir
|---usr
|---home
|---etc
```

File **/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf**:

```
   ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
   DocumentRoot /var/www

    <Directory />
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Order Allow,Deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    Alias /data /var/www/
    <Location /data>
            DAV On
            AuthType Digest
            AuthName "webdav"
            AuthUserFile /usr/local/apache2/.digest_passwd.dav
            Require valid-user
            Order Allow,Deny
            Allow from all
            DirectoryIndex disabled
    </Location>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

The problem is in the point that all paths begin from root server directory.

for example, php command  **opendir('/')** shows list:

```
/
|---var
|---usr
|---home
|---etc
```

but I need list like that

```
/
|---subdir
|---script1.php
```

So, how can I make Apache think that **'/'** means not root web server directory, but root apache directory?

Comment: I don' think that's possible, better use variable to store document_root absolute path and then concatenate with actual  project folder
//
$site_root='/vat/www/';
opendir($site_root.'subdir'); or take a look here http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

Comment: or use $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: How about changing Apache's root directory ?

Answer (score 0):

opendir takes an actual path not the path of the web server's document root. Thus, opendir("/") is working correctly to show you the server's root directory.

As mentioned by Vladimir, rather use

```
opendir($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]);
```

or probably better for security

```
opendir(filter_var($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"], FILTER_INPUT_STRING));
```